# How to initialize an array in a class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

Working in [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) on [Mac OS X Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_v10.5) in C++:

I have the following code:

```
class Foo{

private:
    string bars[];

public:
    Foo(string initial_bars[]){
        bars = initial_bars;
    }
}
```

It does not compile and throws the following error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::string*' to 'std::string [0u]'
```

I notice that removing the line `bars = initial_bars;` solves the problem.
It seems like I am not doing the assignment correctly. How could I go about fixing this problem?

EDIT:

The variable bars is an array of strings. In the main function I initialize it like this:

```
string bars[] = {"bar1", "bar2", "bar3"};
```

But it can contain an arbitrary number of members.

Comment: For starters, the declaration `string bars[]` itself is an error in ISO C++ compliant code - the fact that your compiler lets you do it (and, judging by the error message, treats it as `string bars[0]`) means that it offers that as an extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays behave like const pointers, you can't assign pointers to them. You also can't directly assign arrays to each other.

You either

- use a pointer member variable
- have a fixed size of `bar`s you get and initialize your member array with its contents
- just use a reference to a `std` container like `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to "value-initialize" array members as follows:

```
class A {
public:
  A () 
  : m_array ()       // Initializes all members to '0' in this case
  {
  }

private:
  int m_array[10];
};
```

For [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structures) types this is important as if you don't list 'm_array' in the member initialization list then the array elements will have indeterminate values.

In general it's better to initialize members in the member-initialization-list, otherwise the members will be initialized twice:

```
A (std::vector<int> const & v)
// : m_v ()   // 'm_v' is implicitly initialized here
{
  m_v = v;    // 'm_v' now assigned to again
}
```

More efficiently written as:

```
A (std::vector<int> const & v)
: m_v (v)
{
}
```